# Why does ATI Radeon have choppy display on Linux?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, display, radeon

I'm using Radeon HD 7700M on Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm using Catalyst 13.1 as the graphics driver. The problem is that I keep getting these horizontal lines appearing on the screen that look like the computer is refreshing display slowly. It happens particularly when I'm watching an HD video or when there is rapid motion being displayed, but it could happen at other time like when I'm browsing the internet or using the file browser; But when I switch to Intel GPU things get better, the problem still exists but to a much lesser degree.

Do all Linux users have this problem with Radeon 7 series?
Is there a way to fix this problem without switching to Intel GPU?
Is there anything that I need to upgrade or downgrade or features that I could disable to reduce the problem?

Comment: a) Can you exclude if this a Compiz issue? b) Does this happen with other versions of the Catalyst drivers? c) or the open source drivers? (If you game, the open sources might not provide the best performance though) // I think the consensus remains on the proprietary Catalyst drivers, that they way behind Nvidia's proprietary drivers or Intel's drivers (even better, built in to the kernel), and this sad state the of the drivers makes AMD a bit less desirable option for Ubuntu (or Linux in general).

Comment: yes, I can exclude Compiz being the issue and I've only tried the driver that I've mentioned. I know that the open source drivers aren't good for 3D, but could they be better than the proprietary driver for 2D?

Comment: What you're describing is called screen tearing and common to AMD cards under FGLRX. Try activating tear free mode in the catalyst control center (display options --> tear free). This will reduce graphics performance, though.